# My FlightData Master Data Structure does not conform to Decodable when using other Data Structures

Tags: swift, structure, codable, decodable

I am trying to build a master structure of data that is built based upon other model structures I have used. Below is my code:

```
struct AirportFlightData: Codable {
    let scheduled_arrivals = [Scheduled_Arrivals].self
    let scheduled_departures = [Scheduled_Departures].self
    let arrivals = [ArrivalData].self
    let departures = [DepartureData].self
}
```

All of the above conform to Codable, (Inclusive of Encode/Decodable) however this master structure does not. How can I resolve this?

Comment: I think you likely mean to use the pattern `let scheduled_arrivals: [Scheduled_Arrivals]` rather than `let scheduled_arrivals = [Scheduled_Arrivals].self`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct AirportFlightData: Codable {
    let scheduled_arrivals : [Scheduled_Arrivals]
    let scheduled_departures : [Scheduled_Departures]
    let arrivals : [ArrivalData]
    let departures : [DepartureData]
}
```

You set the type in swift with `:` not `.self`.

Comment: It threw an error when I didn’t declare self which made no sense to me - I’m not at my desk but it was expecting some sort of call from what I remember

Comment: @TVProducer what error, this assumes that all the other Types conform to `Codable` per your question.

Comment: They do. I just remembered. I’m an idiot. I tried setting it EQUAL not of type. I’m an idiot. Thanks!